# Webmin cron job command

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, command, webmin

I want to perform a cron job to run a php script that deletes a bunch of image files but it seems like not working and there's no output generated even though I echo something. I am using Codeigniter php framework I would like to know what is the correct command to run the script. Below is my current command template which is not workable.

> /usr/bin/php -q /home/something/public_html controller method

Comment: open cpanel and goto cron jobs and add new cron with time duration

Comment: I am not sure if my command is correct.

Comment: I have found out the correct command and it works.

Comment: can u try adding that command into a shell script and put the shell in cron job instead?